# Is the last appearance of a local variable treated as an rvalue in C++11?

Tags: c++11, move-semantics

Are local variables' last appearance in their scope treated as an rvalue? (Like in return statements.) Eg. in the code below, are the strings moved into the vector or `V.push_back(std::move(newitem))` should be written explicitly ?

```
struct Element
{
std::string s1 {};
std::string s2 {};
}

void f()
{

std::vector<Element> V;

 while (condition())
 {
     Element newitem { };

     newitem.s1 = "example1";
     newitem.s2 = "example2";

     V.push_back(newitem);
 };
};
```

Comment: The `return` case is special and specifically involves copy-elision, not plain move semantics (the new object is created directly in caller space, not constructed locally then `move`-ed). Otherwise, there is nothing special about the final appearance in a scope.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example `newitem` is an lvalue (its a named object) so no move construtor will be used. Compiler will use move constructor if you provide an rvalue, as in:

```
V.push_back(std::move(newitem))
```

where xvalue is passed to push_back. So yes, you should use `std::move` explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

No it will not call `std::move` by it self.
You may try this code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
struct Element
{
    std::string s1;
    std::string s2;
    Element() = default;
    Element(const Element&) = default;
    Element(Element&& other){
        other.s1 = s1;
        other.s2 = s2;
        s1 = "";
        s2 = "";
    }
    ~Element()
    {
        std::cout << s1 << " " << s2 << std::endl;
    }
};

void f()
{
    auto V = new std::vector<Element>{};  // deny destucting the vector
    V->reserve(10000); // deny reallocation
    size_t i{ 0 };
    while (i++<5)
    {
        Element newitem{};
        newitem.s1 = "example1";
        newitem.s2 = "example2";
        V->push_back(newitem);
    }
}
int main()
{
    f();
    std::getchar();
}
```

[Live Demo](http://cpp.sh/5nwnf)

> **Result:**
>
> example1 example2
>
> example1 example2
>
> example1 example2
>
> example1 example2
>
> example1 example2

Try it with `V->push_back(std::move(newitem));` and see the differences.

P.S. Code above causes memory leak. It was do it on purpose in order to preventing calling the destructor.

Answer (score 0):

`newitem` has a name, so as long as you don't use `std::move` it will be treated as lvalue .

Interestingly, building this code with Visual studio 2013 with `/O2`, the compiler did not optimized any of the calls away. (you would expect that since no-one uses `newitem` afterwards the compiler will convert everything to in place construction)

Performance wise, you can also use `emplace_back`:

```
V.emplace_back(std::string("hello"),std::string("world"));
```

(the `std::string` wrapper is not redandant)